# Removing PDF Subject Tag with Exiftool

Tags: windows, command-line, exiftool

Can someone help me understand why the following command will overwrite the Title tag, but not delete the subject tag of my PDF file?

`exiftool -Title="My Title" -Subject= myfile.pdf`

Thanks!

R.

Comment: What version would it be?  "exiftool -ver"

Comment: I have version 11.84

Comment: Do you end up with an empty Subject?

Comment: What program are you using to see the "Subject"?  Does the `Subject` still appear if you run the command in [exiftool FAQ #3](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q3) or does the value appear some place else?

Comment: The value still shows in Acrobat Reader DC, as well as PDF Architect, but indeed not with `exiftool -a myfile.pdf` (the tag is not even listed). A bug in exiftool?
@GerardH.Pille: no the value of Subject is left unchanged.

Comment: Then I would deduce that the tag is not really "Subject".  Would you mind showing the output of "exiftool myfile.pdf" ?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Your hunch was correct.  An additional tag had the same data and Adobe Reader was pulling from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The detailed answer was discussed [here](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=10767.msg57265#msg57265).

Answer (score 0):

Exiftool uses an [incremental update method](https://www.debenu.com/kb/incremental-updates/), part of the 1.7 PDF specification.  This type of update is reversable, as mentioned on the [ExifTool PDF tags page](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/PDF.html).  In order to remove the old data, you would have to re-linearized the file with a program such as [qpdf](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/).

The example file your provided on the [ExifTool forums](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=10767.msg57258#msg57258) created with PDF Creator showed that the value you used for `Subject` also was added to the `XMP:Description` tag.  As these two tags are corresponding, Adobe Reader will display data from either tag as the "Subject".

Comment: Linearization with qpdf does not appear to work. Acrobat Reader DC still displays the original value in the Subject field...